# Regarding Dual Booting of Linux with Windows as primary os

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, distributions

First of all is dual booting available for all linux distros?

Second [these are my laptop config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2xnf.jpg) and I have Dell Inspiron N5050.
So which linux distro (dual boot capable) will be best to run as dual boot with Windows 10 Pro?

Also please tell the safe method to install it as dual boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is not a question of Linux, but a question of boot manager:
You can use the Windows boot manager to boot Windows and Linux, but that is rather tricky (for experienced users). I had managed it for Windows/7, but couldn't for Windows 10.

Today's Linux all use GRUB2 as boot manager (which is more messy (to customize) than GRUB1) that can boot Windows and Linux (and others).
Some Linux distributions always overwrite the (Windows) boot manager when updating the kernel, more recent distribution do not.

Likewise in Windows 7, Windows Updates frequently over-wrote the Linux boot manager, making it difficult to boot Linux after that.
I had a version of Acronis True Image that could restore just the MBR/boot loader, fixing that problem, but recent versions of the product are unable to do that.

Finally the ability to use the GRUB boot manager also depends on your partitioning as grub installs a part of itself in the "gap" between partitions, preferably between the MBR and the start of the first partition in the classic MS_DOS partitioning scheme (I'm unsure about (U)EFI/GPT).
If you have a very old partitioning where the partition starts immediately after the MBR, GRUB may be unable to install in that disk.
Partitions created in newer times align the partitions to be aligned to 1MB boundaries, leaving enough space for GRUB to install.

Finally there are tools (e.g. GNU parted) that are (or at least were) able to move (and possibly resize) partitions without data loss to "open a gap" between partitions.

It is possible that some Windows functionality gets lost if the boot manager is not that of Windows.
One example I know is "Try & Decide" offered by Acronis True Image.

Answer (score 2):

It should dual boot fine! Most distros support it in an easy fashion, (you'll want to shrink your windows partitions in windows first though,) the typical way it's done is linux installs the GRUB boot manager which is booted first when you turn on your machine. That gives you an option of loading linux, or handing over to the Windows boot manager. You may have to disable SecureBoot from windows before you start, but I don't think your model has it

The thing to look out for is Windows has been known to overwrite the GRUB boot loader occasionally, which can scare you if you're not prepared for it, but it is easy enough to recover from

Typically linux is known for using fewer resources to run than its counterparts, so not having a fast enough cpu or big enough memory isn't usually a major concern

The one sticking point is that Dell doesn't share firmware with the open source communities, so you might hit strange hardware incompatibilities, most likely certain laptop-specific functions like screen dimming or lid state detection not working properly, or possibly nothing will be wrong and it'll work flawlessly!

Typically the linux stock firmware is fantastic, especially on slightly older machines, and going through something of a golden age right now. Your machine model doesn't show up on the [Debian compatibility list](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Dell), or the [Ubuntu compatibility list](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?query=5050&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&level=&vendors=Dell), but that doesn't necessarily mean it won't work, just that it hasn't been confirmed working yet. Other Dell Inspirons are on there so some do work.

Because the install procedures for Ubuntu and Debian are so slick now, (far better than windows, subjectively,) and because they're so competent at handling partitions / windows, unless this is your workhorse and only machine, I would recommend giving it a go with a small partition and seeing if it works for you! Data loss is always possible when you start tinkering with partitions, but major disasters from linux installs are rare these days and if the linux partition doesn't work, you can always have Windows "repair" the boot partition

Take backups of anything from Windows you don't want to lose, make sure you have you licence key in case something completely unexpected happens and you need to recover from a disk, just to be on the safe side, make sure not to overwrite the recovery partition if one exists, and experiment!

Comment: Another important thing when talking about dual boot are differences between legacy/UEFI and MBR/GPT.

Comment: I am thinking to switch from windows to Linux completely. So see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/582449/407960) and help please.

Comment: Very good point about legacy(MBR)/UEFI(GPT)

If you do go with dual boot Pragyan, all you really need to know is that legacy is the old boot standard, and UEFI is the new one. The distro you install should detect which mode is set in the BIOS and handle it correctly 

The real difference in use is that with Legacy, you'd have both Windows and Linux listed in Grub (Linux's boot manager)

Whereas with UEFI, you're more likely to have the Grub and Windows boot managers separated by the motherboard. If you need to change from the default to the other, you'd do it with F8 or F12 at boot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, all Linux distros can dual boot. I can't think of any reason why one wouldn't be able to do this, and I'm very confident that all major distros will do this with no problem.

Which distro you should install is a very broad question with a lot of highly debated and personal answers, and there's no general 'correct answer'.

For your case though, it sounds like you're relatively new to Linux. Is that fair?

In that case, [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) is probably the best choice to start with. It's comparatively very easy to set up and will happily dual boot with Windows, there's a huge number of guides on how to do exactly that (including Ubuntu's [own wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)), and it's generally good at offering help and stopping you making major mistakes (e.g. warning you before you accidentally wipe your Windows install, for example).

Comment: Yes I am new to Linux.  Are my Laptop Configuration dual boot compatible?

Comment: I am thinking to switch from windows to Linux completely. So see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/582449/407960) and help please.